# how to specify the gtk+ combobox position popup

Tags: c, list, popup, gtk

I use glade and GTK to design the interface of my application.
My question is about the position of the popup associated with a GtkComboBox.
My popup appears horizontally under the GtkComboBox but vertically centered.

Gnome Developper says "The style in which the selected value is displayed, and the style of the popup is determined by the current theme".
How can I know that theme and where I can fix it for a popup.

I have noticed that from fresh start (power up) the popup in glade is attached to the ComboBox.
It is only after starting my application that the issue of vertically centered popup appears. It appears in the app, but also in glade itself!

I don't have the faintest idea on where to search for the issue.

Pierre

Comment: would you provide a code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the issue.
Not GTK+ nor my application SW.
I use a SW keyboard and it is it which modify the windows current theme!
Why I don't know. But clearly the issue appears when this keyboard is on the screen.
It is "matchbox-keyboard".